# Web site using js files

Tags: javascript, iphone

I'm have a problems with a website using JS files. There is only 1 page and the problem is with the menus which are using anchor tabs. If you use an Iphone and you click on the menu it will flick and then go to the section. Is there away to get rid of this.

Here is the js files that I'm using:

```
jquery-1.6.1.min.js
jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js
jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js
jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js
jquery.smoothscroll.js
init.js
```

Any help would be great if you need any of the coding please let me know.

The web page with the problem is http://wirestream.tv

Comment: Can you give us a link to your page, or a jsfiddle?

Comment: "Flick"? What is that supposed to mean? It's supposed to simulate flicking (on an iphone with a finger), right?

Comment: @Zove:
No the client does not want the flicking on the Iphone or and Ipad.

Comment: needs to be a smooth transition.

Answer (score 0):

In the event handlers on the menu items, you can do:

```
function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    [.. the rest..]
}
```

which will prevent the browser to follow the `href` link to the anchor on the page.

- [Read more about preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault)

---

I assume the menu item already have a click event handler:

```
$(".menu-item").on("click", function() {});
```

Comment: Ah, I assume there is a click event already on the menu item, right?

Comment: No the last designer does not have this. example They have a menu called Services code likes like this
<li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
which scrolls down to the anchor called services.

Comment: Part of their code
$('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
    if (  locationPath == thisPath
    && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
      if (target) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        $(this).click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000, function() {
            location.hash = target;
          });
        });
      }
    }

Comment: OK, I may have misunderstood what was the initial problem. I did not see the link to the page before now, you should include it in the original question. However, the way the page is now, the menu does not work at all. I'm pretty sure the problem is related to jquery.smoothscroll.js - try to comment out that script in your original page, and verify that things works well then.